# WooCommerce override add to Cart Button

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am new to WP and coding in it, so excuse me if this is a stupid question.

I want to run a function that will return a TRUE or FALSE value when a customer clicks add to basket button.

My question is

1. How do I find out what and where the function is that runs when the add to basket is clicked.
2. How do I ensure that the work I do is not over written when there is a WooCom upgrade?

Thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are new to WordPress you might not know about hooks.

WordPress hooks are functions which can change default functionality.

So, answer to you second question - how to be sure that your code won't be  over written is by simply using Action and Filter hooks in your theme function.php file. In this way you can update woocommerce plugin without warryng that your custom functionality will dissapear.

Woocomerce use add_to_cart() function to add products in cart. This function already has hooks which allows you to modify default functionality. More about this function - [link](http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_cartadd_to_cart/) . As you can see in Call hooks section there are six hooks. Im not shure how correctly return true or false during add to cart process, because add_to_cart() function throw exception error if something went wrong.

But if you'll try use WordPress hooks, in your theme function.php file the code should be like this

```
// define the woocommerce_add_to_cart callback 
function action_woocommerce_add_to_cart( $array, $int, $int ) { 
    // make action magic happen here... 
}; 

// add the action 
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'action_woocommerce_add_to_cart', 10, 3 );
```

Could you give more information why you want to do that?

'woocommerce_add_to_cart' hook usage based on your situation.

```
// define the woocommerce_add_to_cart callback 
function action_woocommerce_add_to_cart( $cart_item_key, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation, $cart_item_data ) { 
    $vendor = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'vendor', true );
    if($vendor === 'something') {
      return false; //you should return (throw new Exception)
    }
}; 

// add the action 
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'action_woocommerce_add_to_cart', 10, 6 );
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I am trying to build something to assist Micro Enterprises in my town.  So  I am trying a different approach on a  multi vendor store. I have a WooCom Store running wc-marketplace.  I have modified the payment gateway so that it pays the vendor directly instead of me.  The problem is now I can only allow a customer to check out with items from a single vendor.  So I need a function to check if there is an item in the basket, if so who is the vendor and is it the same vendor and the item being added.  If not there needs to be and error, if yes, it can go in.

Comment: I think you can use 'woocommerce_add_to_cart' hook. It takes 6 parameters and one of them is $product_id. Inside the hook you can check product meta information about vendor and return true of false.

Comment: Perfect thank, lastly, inside woocommerce_add_to_cart, how would I call a hook from wc-marketplace?  Thank you for the assistance

Comment: Hi Tautvydas, I have written a function is there any way I can communicate with you directly to show you what I have and ask one more question.  Thank you